# How to ask for email response in very kind way

Tags: phrase-request, sentence-structure

I am writing an email to my work team. I am sharing with them a new suggestion. I would like to have their opinion on this new idea. Therefore, I would like to write a nice sentence asking for their response.

**Here is my try**

I would be very happy to hear from you about this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite a good start. In fact you could go ahead and use your sentence.

Something you could do to tweak it would be something like:

> I would be happy to hear your feedback about this point.

That way is just a little more specific about encouraging comment.

But your version is good too. If you are writing a longer email, just check your present active or passive voices as there were a couple of mistakes in your question. "I **am writing** an email ...", "I **am** sharing ..."